# Angular Build Error with baseHref set to ./ for Electron Integration

Tags: angular, electron

I'm working on an Angular project that will be executed within Electron. To ensure Electron can locate the necessary files, I've set the baseHref to ./. However, this configuration breaks my Angular build, especially when it includes libraries.

The build errors are consistent and involve imports from Angular Material and Angular Common. The directories exist, and I'm puzzled as to why these imports are failing. Here's a sample error:

```bash
Error: libs/libname/src/lib/products-table/project-overview.component.ts:21:14 - error NG3004: Unable to import directive NgIf.        
  The symbol is not exported from C:/Users/bla/node_modules/@angular/common/index.d.ts (module '@angular/common').

21 export class SomeComponent {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  libs/libname/node_modules/@angular/common/index.d.ts:2024:1
    2024 export declare class NgIf<T = unknown> {
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2025     private _viewContainer;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     ...
    2062     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<NgIf<any>, "[ngIf]", never, { "ngIf": { "alias": "ngIf"; "required": false; }; "ngIfThen": { "alias": "ngIfThen"; "required": false; }; "ngIfElse": { "alias": "ngIfElse"; "required": false; }; }, {}, never, never, true, never>;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2063 }
         ~
    The directive is declared here.
```

When I remove baseHref or set it to / (the default), the issues are resolved. Here's a snippet of my configuration:

```json
...
 "build-relative": {
            ...
            "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/apps/project",
                "baseHref": "./",
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
```

Has anyone encountered this issue when integrating Angular with Electron? How can I resolve this while keeping the baseHref set to ./? Any compiler settings I maybe should have a look into?
The project libs are generated with the default schematics by nx / angular schematics.
I honestly don't know what information is needed to solve this problem.
**Update** The error only occurs in a lib that I import, not the project itself.

**Reserach I conducted**
I found this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14587, but my errors seem not related to import paths of images
This post https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36060 also describes the problem. However, in this setup, I need to recompile my project when I make changes even if I just serve the angular project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported CommonModule in your angular module. As far as baseHref is concerned, you can update `<base href="./">`  in index.html or build your project with baseHref option like
`ng build --configuration production --base-href ./`

Comment: This is what I am already doing and leads to the problem